# Sqlite select statement results in an error whenever i open the intent

Tags: java, android, sqlite, content-values

Here is my code

The first 3 functions are in the database class

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

        String creation_query3= "CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_Doctor + "(" + Doctor_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Doctor_NAME
                + " TEXT, " + Doctor_PHONE + "TEXT )";

        db.execSQL(creation_query3);

    }

public void adddoctor(String pName, String ph){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Doctor_NAME,pName);
        cv.put(Doctor_PHONE,ph);
        db.insert(TABLE_Doctor, null, cv);
        db.close();
}

public String getAllDoctors(){

        Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT "+Doctor_NAME+" FROM "+ TABLE_Doctor, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String s=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Doctor_NAME));
        cursor.close();
        return s;           
    }
```

And this is in the main class

```
{

String test=db.getAllDoctors();

textView.setText(test.toString());

}
```

Here is the error:

```
01-17 14:30:02.490 27929-27929/com.example.ghumdan.finalprojectkg 

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                  

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{com.example.ghumdan.finalprojectkg/com.example.ghumdan.finalprojectkg.AddPatient}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
                                                                                        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
                                                                                        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                                                                                        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                                                                                        at com.example.ghumdan.finalprojectkg.Database.getAllDoctors(Database.java:107)
                                                                                        at com.example.ghumdan.finalprojectkg.AddPatient.onCreate(AddPatient.java:35)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi i mean the app crashes

Comment: Post your error. `The app crashes` - not without a logcat.

Comment: Looks as an error `" TEXT, " + Doctor_PHONE + "TEXT )"`

Comment: `Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0` Your cursor is empty. It seems that you didn't insert any record into it.

Comment: this error mean cursor fetching column returning index 0...generally this happen when it call column which do not exists (calling wrong,empty column ) in table...I would suggest to first check weather your table is created with column you have specified or not and you are call right column...

Comment: @Mohit `... with a size of 0` means `no records`

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi I do agree but, I encountered same problem yesterday only as I was calling the column with other name (that was not in the table) and got same error...I corrected the name and it worked...

Comment: @Mohit how can i make sure the table is created?

Comment: @v.ladynev u are right,,, it worked now

Comment: You have problem with the sql query...you have missing space before TEXT for column Doctor_PHONE......Should be Doctor_PHONE + " TEXT )";

Comment: @Psypher Thanks! it is working now